# Check if url is Reachable Android with timeout response

Tags: android

I have write function that check if address is Reachable or not, my problem is that when response is slow or go in timeout it freeze the UI as long Does not receive the response or catch exception.

My function is:

```
public static boolean isURLReachable() {
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) App.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
   if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
      try {
         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
         URL url = new URL(ConfigData.CHECK_IP); 
         HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        urlc.setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT_CALL);
                        urlc.setReadTimeout(TIME_OUT_CALL);
                        urlc.connect();
                        if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {        // 200 = "OK" code (http connection is fine).
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                        return  false;
                    }
                    catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
                        return false;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
```

There is a way to not block the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Socket for this:

```
public static boolean isURLReachable() {
    final  URL url  = new URL("your url here");

     final  Socket socket = new Socket();
                            socket.setSoTimeout(200);
                            socket.connect(new   InetSocketAddress(url.getHost(),url.getPort()),200);
                    isConect =socket.isConnected();
                    socket.close();
            return isConect;
}


where 200 is the required timeout.
```

Comment: hello thankyou!
It return IllegalArgumentException host error

Comment: I tried with both, with debug seems that error is on socket.connect()

Now I have this: socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.20",80),2000);

Comment: I have found the problem with debug, probably the poblem si I make this connection in mainThread
Method threw 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException' exception.
this is the real exception.

Comment: but not resolve the problem, the unique way that I'have found is launch function on new thread